# How to get Assembly calculations in int format

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm still learning asm. im trying to find out why ax reg turns to 28 and not 25. I'm using emu8086.

```
mov dx,0h    ; dx = 0
mov ax,0050h ; ax = 50
mov bx,2     ; bx = 2
    
div bx ; ax / 2 =50.
       ; but ax is now 28?
```

Comment: Mind the `h` in `0050h`. Those are hex numbers, and `50/2 = 28` in hexadecimal.

Comment: Use your debugger to look at values; hopefully it shows them in both hex and decimal.  Also, never use `div` to divide by 2: use `shr` by 1.

Comment: The 'f' in 38fh is part of the number, so it's 38Fh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Values in assembly are usually in hex, explicitly stated with the `h` at the of `0050h`

> `50h` or `0x50` is `80` in base 10
> `80/2=40`
> `40` in hex is `0x28`
> therefore your result is `0x28` or `28h`